# Match a string with no white space in between text but may have leading spaces/zeros

Tags: regex, abap

Regular expression that matches based on the below

- It is min 12 or max 13 characters
- Can have leading spaces/Zeros
- No blank spaces in the String
- Not all Zeros/spaces
- Correct Match:
  "   ABCDEFGHIJ"
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLM"
- Wrong Match:
  "ABCD    IJKL"

Comment: Can you put some example (text to parse and text to extract/detect)

Comment: I presume no trailing space?

Comment: @user2991913, Our browsers were automatically normalizing the three leading spaces so it looked like there was only one.  I think that's why everyone jumped to the conclusion that you were looking for either 13 characters or a space followed by 12 characters.  CoverosGene adding backticks didn't help because the inline formatting mechanism is still subject to normalization.  If whitespace is significant, you *must* use the block form of code formatting.

Comment: by the way, your "correct" match, " ABCDEFGHIJ" is 11 chars long, leading space inclusive which doesnt fit with your first request :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying the whole string has to be 12 or 13 characters long *including* the leading whitespace?  This will work in most regex flavors:

```
^(?=.{12,13}$)\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

I'm not sure about ABAP though.  Many of the search hits I've found suggest that it supports lookaheads, but if you're really using POSIX standard regexes, this won't work.  You would probably have to do the length check in a separate test.

**UPDATE:** To prevent a match of all zeroes, you'll need to add another lookahead:

```
^(?=.{12,13}$)(?!0+$)\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

**UPDATE 2:** It just occurred to me that you probably don't want strings like `" 000000000"` -- i.e., all zeroes plus leading spaces.  This regex will cover that:

```
^(?=.{12,13}$)(?!\s*0+$)\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

Comment: It's not going to match all spaces because `[A-Za-z0-9]+` has to match at least one letter or digit.  For the other requirement, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^ *[A-Za-z0-9]{12,13}$
```

Comment: Thanks, but i allows only one leading space it should allow multiple leading spaces for e.g. "    ABCDEFGH"

Comment: @user2991913: Are you sure it allows only 1 space. I have `^ *` which means 0 or ore leading spaces.

Comment: Which language/tool you're using to test it?

Comment: REGEX_TOY extended regular expressions in accordance with POSIX standard 1003.2.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in any of the online regex testers?

Comment: See it [**working on regexpal**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%20*%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%7B12%2C13%7D%24&input=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ABCDEFGHIJKL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ABCD%20EFGHIJKL%0AABCDEFGHIJKL%0AABCDEFGHIJ)

Comment: All the highlighted lines are matching lines. Very first has many leading spaces and it is matching.

Comment: 1st highlighted one is not counting maximum length 13

Answer (score 0):

```
\s*\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{12,13}\b
```

This doesn't require the string to be on its own line. If you don't actually care about matching the initial whitespace you can get rid of the `\s*`

Comment: If the strings you are matching are on their own lines then @anubhava's answer is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You just want optional leading spaces:

```
\s*[A-Za-z0-9]{12}
```

Comment: He specifically said in a comment to Anubhava's answer that it's not restricted to one leading space.

Comment: @Tobberoth silly me for just reading the question. Changed `?` to `*`.

Comment: Which makes it into a copy of previous answers, which are not even correct in the first place.